# Flash message not showing in CakePHP?

Tags: session, cakephp, flash-message

I am trying to show a flash message in my ctp. I already declared

```
var $helpers = array('Html','Session','Form','Js');
```

at `app_controller.php` and I write the code

```
$this->Session->setFlash("Error!!!!!!!!!")
```

in my controller. But it doesn't show up in my view `.ctp` file.

I've a own template. Flash message doesn't show up in my own template.

Comment: Can you show us a little bit more code? Knowing the context, not only a single line, is usually helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare

```
var $helpers = array('Session');
```

in your controller?

If you you have declared it, did you try echoing

```
$this->Session->flash()
```

in your view?

Comment: I already declared var $helpers= array('Session') and i already test $this->Session->flash() in my view but it doesn't show flash message.

Comment: @shariphwar He/She is trying to say that `$this->Session->flash()` does not echo by itself. You have to explicitly put `echo $this->Session->flash()`

Comment: elitalon is right. you have tto explicitly put echo $this->Session->flash() in your view ^___^ sorry for not being clear on my answer..